# Linq.Dynamic throws exception attempting to convert nullable int to string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using the System.Linq.Dynamic library DynamicQuery as part of a solution using EF on .NET Framework 4.0 to try and convert a Nullable (int?) to String within the Select similar to:

```
query= "new(Convert.ToString(columnName) as stringColumn)";
IQueryable result = queryable.Select(query, parameters[]);
```

How do I get the Expression.Call to work and return the string equivalent of a Nullable column?

Thanks,
John

---

Things I've tried:

1. I've tried sending Convert.ToString(columnName) as part of the query:

System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance) in c:\Projects\DynamicQuery.cs:line 3461

1. I've tried using (columnName).toString() and receive the following:

System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: Methods on type 'Int32?' are not accessible
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression instance) in c:\Projects\DynamicQuery.cs:line 3453

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "new(Convert.ToString((int?)columnName))";
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the query string. No property or field 'int' exists in type 'DynamicClass1'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
query = "new(Convert.ToString(Int32(columnName)))"
```

or

```
query = "new((Int32(columnName)).ToString())"
```

Comment: Please explain your answer